# How to do the RESET test on an AR model?

Tags: r, time-series, non-linear-regression, autoregressive-models

```
> library("lmtest")
> a = arima.sim(list(ar = c(.05, -.05)), 1000)
> b = arima(a, order = c(2, 0, 0))
> resettest(b)
**Error in terms.default(formula) : no terms component nor attribute**
```

Question 1. What I am doing is shown above. What should I do about that? 
(I have tried to put in `type`, `data` and `power` parameter at `resettest()`, result is the same.)

Question 2.If I want to do the same thing on the model below

*=0.5+0.5*(−1)−0.5*(−2)+0.1*(−1)^2+_

which is a ar(2) model plus 0.1_(−1)^2, how to fit this nonlinear model (by using R, thank you!)?

should have earn more reputation... can't post pic below 10 :(

Comment: Have an upvote :) Now you should be able to do it!

Comment: thanks you so much bro! Seems it s an unpopular field :) reputation wise I am still at 8..embarrassing

Comment: guys plz! if you just passed by and know someone who is good at this field, feel free to tag them! thank you so much!

Comment: Actually tagging someone not related to this question wouldn't have any effect (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the first argument of `resettest` is

> formula   - a symbolic description for the model to be tested (or a fitted "lm" object).

So, passing an `Arima` object is not going to work. Instead we may manually define the lagged variables and provide an `lm` object or just the formula:

```
la1 <- Hmisc::Lag(a, 1)
la2 <- Hmisc::Lag(a, 2)
resettest(a ~ la1 + la2)
#
#   RESET test
#
# data:  a ~ la1 + la2
# RESET = 0.10343, df1 = 2, df2 = 993, p-value = 0.9018
```

Now your second model is nonlinear in variables but linear in parameters, so the same estimation methods still apply. (I'm assuming that the true DGP remains the same and you just want to test a new specification.) In particular,

```
resettest(a ~ la1 + la2 + I(la2^2))
#
#   RESET test
#
# data:  a ~ la1 + la2 + I(la2^2)
# RESET = 0.089211, df1 = 2, df2 = 992, p-value = 0.9147
```